# Android: Is read process with AssetManager threadsafe?

Tags: android, android-ndk, assets

I'm using AssetManager to read data from apk. I wonder if the set of APIs are threadsafe. e.g.,

```
AAsset_seek
AAsset_getLength
AAsset_read
```

I cannot find obvious info on this matter from the official documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html

or source code:
http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/include/android/asset_manager.h

Thanks!

Comment: why wouldn't it be, assets are immutable after all ?

Comment: @njzk2 you're jumping to a conclusion that isn't supported by your evidence.  You can certainly build stateful ways to access immutable resources.  It's not even unusual; think about methods that might cache immutable data that's expensive to read.  No reason to assume that those caches would be threadsafe.  (I'm not arguing anything about AssetManager here - I don't know if it has threadsafe methods or not.)